# ASP .NET MVC rewrite img src url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have images in my web app that are currently retrieved from another domain:

```
<img src="https://images.other.net/{folder}/{filename}"/>
```

I want to rewrite all image urls to a specific action in my own domain but using some parts of the path above. The new URL should look like:

```
<img src="https://images.mydomain.net/en/home/getimage?name={filename}&folder={folder}"/>
```

where `folder` and `filename` are dynamic values.

I want to see if I can do it without actually changing all paths 1 by 1.
Can I do it either by MVC Routing rules or by URL rewrite rules in the `web.config` file?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the list of several options to do that.
This list also contains the benefits/problems you will face using these methods:

1. Changing all paths:

   - You can change all the paths at once by using the find and replace option if the base URL of all the paths is the same.
   - The shortcut key for Find and Replace option is `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `R` .
   - If you will keep the base URL in multiple files/places in the code, it will create a problem for you if the URL will change in the future, you have to replace them again.
2. Put the base URL in a `web.config` key *(Recommended)*

   - **Better approach is to create a key in the `web.config` file and put the base URL there so that even if it changes in the future you just have to change the URL once in the `web.config` file**.
3. Using IIS URL Rewrite

   - You can get help from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) to create some URL rewrite rules.
   - For rewrite rule with dynamic values see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275831/iis-url-rewriting-change-a-querystring-key-and-value-into-a-route).